# Pass data from A and B fragments to C fragements

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created three fragments **A**, **B** and **C**. In fragment **A** I'm having **First Name** and **Last Name**. In fragment **B** I'm having **Age**, **City**, **Area** and **Address**. In **C** I'm having **Profession** and **Experience**. In frag **C** I'm also having a button which sends all the info to the server. Now how can I have the info from fragment **A** and **B** in fragment **C**. I have used `Bundle` to send the info but it's a tedious task. Any simple method available?

E.g.:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle ();
args.putString ("first_name", strFirstName);
args.putString ("last_name", strLastName);
```

Comment: what's the problem of using Bundle?! It's the best approach I can see for that. Did it work using Bundle?

Comment: better to store data in a commom class from your fragments and use it whereever you want.

Comment: Why are you using 3 fragments for this? Surely First Name, Last Name, Age, City, Area, Address, Profession and Experience all relate to one person? Why don't you do this all in a single `Fragment` or in a single `Activity`?

Comment: This is a good way of sending values from fragment to fragment.... but as you are asking for other ways you can use a static variable in which you asign the value in Fragment A just before pushing fragment c. then you can access the same static variable in Fragment c's oncreateview() method.... THis is a very bad process.

Comment: ya it worked flawlessly.But i read someWhere to create an interface

Comment: @Squonk my clients need dem in diffrent views and also i heard fragments have advantage over Activity so i used fragments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing data from fragment A and B to C, pass them to the `Activity` via callback, and then pass the "send to server" action callback so that the `Activity` handles it:

```
class Fragment A {
// fragment definition

    public interface OnUserInformationTypedListener {
        public void onUserInformationTyped(String name, String lastName);
    }
}

class FragmentB {
// fragment definition

    public interface OnUserExtraInformationTypedListener {
        public void onUserExtraInformationTyped(int age, String address);
    } 
}

class FragmentC {
// fragment definition

    public interface OnUserCareerInformationTypedListener {
        public void onUserCareerTyped(String profession, String experience);
        public void onSendToServer();
    }
}
```

Then make the `Activity` implements all interfaces:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnUserInformationTypedListener, 
    OnUserExtraInformationTypedListener, OnUserCareerInformationTypedListener {

    @Override
    public void onUserInformationTypedListener(String name, String lastName) {
         // Probably pass local variable to private attributes
    }

    // Override the rest of the interface's methods

    @Override
    public void onSendToServer() {
        // Send information to the server logic
    }
}
```

And finally, make the `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` and `FragmentC` each one an instance of their respective callback, i.e:

```
// Inside FragmentA
private OnUserInformationTypedListener listener = null;
```

And then you pass the listener reference to it, Either by calling `Fragment#onAttach(Activity)` or via public method:

```
// Inside FragmentA
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    listener = (OnUserInformationTypedListener) activity;
}

// if you prefer public setter then create the setter and call it from the Activity:
// Inside Activity#onCreate or wherever you instantiate the fragment
FragmentA fa = new FragmentA();
fa.setOnUserInformationTypedListener(this);
```

For more information on how to communicate `Fragments` via the host `Activity` (this is the right way to do it), read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: but sir the button is in the Fragment C then how can i send the info through activity???

Comment: the button's onClick() method (inside FragmentC) will call `listener.onSendToServer()`

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Very Good Answer +1 up

Answer (score 1):

The `Fragment` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) says:

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

So, its not a good idea to pass message from one fragment to another. Check the [basics fragment training docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

> Any simple method available?

You can save the data in a common class, and access the same from the other fragments..

Answer (score 0):

use this i want to pass data on button click  like this

```
    btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
        }
    });
```

and get data oncreate method of fragment

```
@Override
```

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}